# Repetir dados de um JOBJECT

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Consegui fazer meu `JArray` retornar uma lista, nesta lista contém 03 IDs, porém o jeito que o sistema foi feito, fizeram de um jeito para retornar apenas o primeiro `Array`.

Segue o codigo de o que está retornando para a `View`:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult DadosUser2(ListaUsers user_IDs)
{
    UserBLL bll = new UserBLL(context.db);
    JArray users = bll.DadosUser2(user_IDs.user_ids);

    if (users.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("Usuário não encontrado user_id " + user_IDs);

    JObject u = (JObject)users[0];

    return PartialView("DadosUser", u);
}
```

Como posso fazer este `JObject` retornar todos os dados e não só a primeira posição?

Comment: Porque não retornar todo o `Array`? Ou seja: `return PartialView("DadosUser", users);`.

Comment: Essa linha `JObject u = (JObject)users[0];` esta fazendo retornar apenas o primeiro. Tire ela e coloque apenas `return PartialView("DadosUser", users);`

Comment: ao fazer esse return que vcs sugeriram surge o erro Código do erro: PX100
Mensagem: Não é possível converter tipo 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' em 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

Comment: Isso porque sua View está esperando apenas um JObject, vc tem de alterar na sua view para aceitar um JArray

Answer (score 0):

**A linha abaixo esta fazendo retornar apenas o primeiro:**

```
JObject u = (JObject)users[0];
```

**Faça:**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult DadosUser2(ListaUsers user_IDs)
{
    UserBLL bll = new UserBLL(context.db);
    JArray users = bll.DadosUser2(user_IDs.user_ids);

    if (users.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("Usuário não encontrado user_id " + user_IDs);

    return PartialView("DadosUser", users);
}
```

Comment: Isto já foi feito e deu erro...

Comment: Sim, e o Julio Borges respondeu. O mesmo tipo enviado da controller tem que ser o mesmo recebido pela view. Antes você mandava um `JObject`, agora esta mandando um `JArray`. Mude na view o tipo recebido para `JArray`